# Alternative ways to supply data to a recyclerview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cursoradapter

I'm currently using a cursor adapter with my grid view, but i would like use a recyclerview instead.To my knowledge, there is no official way to use a cursor adapter and SQL databases with a recyclerview. So are there any alternative ways to supply data to a recyclerview other than SQL? How do google apps like keep and drive use a recyclerview with variable items? I am new to android, so please forgive me if this question is not meaningful.

Comment: You supply data to RecyclerView using RecyclerView adapter. Check here  http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html for more info

Comment: Yes but my data is in an SQL database, and I can't use it with recycler view adapter since it's not supported officially. So what do I do?

Comment: Query your database and map each row to an Object describing your data then add the same object to a list so at the end you will have a list of objects as same as in your db table. Use this list to populate RecyclerView with an adapter as stated in the example given in the link

Comment: Alright, I'll try that, thanks.